Function Transformation of a line segment.

Problem: Let $y=f(x)$ be the function defined by the line segment connecting the points $(-1,4)$ and $(2,5)$. Describe the transformations and state the new coordinates of the line segment.
a) $y=f(x)+1$
b) $y=f(x+2)$

My answer for a) was vertical translation up 1 unit and the coordinates were $(-1,5)$ and $(2,6)$. No trouble there.
My answer for b) was horizontal translation left $2$ units and the coordinates were $(-3,4)$ and $(0,5)$, but my textbook says the answer in the textbook is $(-1, 6)$ and $(2,7)$.
Why would it be a vertical shift up by two?

Your answer is correct. We are translating the curve by $-2$ units along the $x$ axis.

You're actually correct, I imagine the textbook authors read "$f(x)+2$" by accident.
You can verify this with the point-slope form: your original line is
$$
f(x) = \frac 1 3 (x-2) + 5
$$
Then $f(x+2)$ is
$$
f(x+2) = \frac 1 3 x + 5
$$
This connects the points you describe.
(Desmos demo)

